# How to delete all mail attachments of a set of mails

Tags: email-attachments, mutt

In order to save diskspace, I would like to remove all file attachments of a set of mails (let's say 100) in one folder.

I think this must be possible with [Mutt](http://mutt.org/) and some scripting. For instance using the program [altermime](http://www.pldaniels.com/altermime/).

Ideally, a note is left in the mail specifying that an attachment of a given name has been deleted.

How could this be done?